# How to access the button code from an included layout?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I had included the footer layout inside my home layout. The footer layout contains 3 buttons and it calls three methods in its corresponding footer class.

I am successfully able to display my footer layout on the home layout using the below `include` code.

```
<include layout="@layout/footer"/>
```

The problem i am facing is , the button clicks are not getting executed. It says no such method found exception.

How does the footer buttons can be accessed ?

Comment: set click event at runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also access it with `Button b = (Button) findViewById(idOfButton)`

android treats included layouts as if they were written inside the code, if your button has an id, it is reachable easily

Answer (score 0):

you can access the button this way :

```
Button b = (Button) footerLayout.getChildAt(index);
```

and then you can attach at the button the handler that you prefer.

Comment: do i have to write the same method which i have declared on footer again on home activity ?

Comment: No, if you have the footerLayout variable available, you can handle it whatever you want. All the encapsulated data are available to you.